# Returning a generic type that is a collection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have defined an interface that can be implemented in a generic way. The return type has to be a collection where as the input parameter can be a class or value.

```
public interface IDataRetriever<T, C> where T : ICollection<string>
{

    T GetData(C criteria);
}
```

When I try to return a List I am getting an error "type parameter T cannot be used with the as operation because it does not have a class type."
Tried removing the "as T" but that did not work either.

If I replace  where `T : ICollection<string>` with `List<string>` it works. What is incorrect here ?

```
public class CustomADataRetrieverImpl<T, C>: IDataRetriever<T, C> 
             where T : ICollection<string>
{

    public T GetData(C criteria)
    {

        string myCriteria = criteria as string;
        ICollection<string> data = new List<string>()
            ...
        return data as T;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) expects T to be a reference (or nullable) type, which means that a constraint to class should also be included in your signature.

```
public interface IDataRetriever<T, C>
    where T : ICollection<string>, class

{
    T GetData(C criteria);
}
```

As Jason mentioned in the comments, if T is anything other than a string type or a type derived from T, null will be returned.  However, since your constraint specifies that you expect `ICollection<T>` to be string, this seems acceptable as your question is currently written.

Comment: It should be noted that while this is technically correct, it probably doesn't solve anything. `data as T` will return null for any `T` that isn't `List<string>` or a derived type.

Comment: @JasonWatkins Excellent point, although it wasn't raised specifically in the OP's question, so I didn't address it.

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer to the question you asked, but it's worth noting that you don't seem to understand the `as` operator.

`criteria as string` will return null unless `typeof(C)` is already `string`, making the generic worthless.

Likewise, `return data as T;` will return `null` for any `T` that is not `List<string>` or a type derived from `List<string>`. You could consider requiring a `new()` constructor to allow you to create a new `T` directly.

```
public class CustomADataRetrieverImpl<T, C>: IDataRetriever<T, C> 
             where T : ICollection<string>, new()
{

    public T GetData(C criteria)
    {

        string myCriteria = criteria.ToString();
        T data = new T()
            ...
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not seen that new() notation, as a param before. Looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix `T` and `C` to `List<string>` and `string` you don't need to make `CustomADataRetrieverImpl` generic:

```
public class CustomADataRetrieverImpl : IDataRetriever<List<string>, string>
{
    public List<string> GetData(string criteria)
    {
        var data = new List<string>();
        ...
        return data;
    }
}
```